# MasterDetailPage in Xamarin.Forms has changed?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: MasterDetailPage by Default in Xamarin.Forms(Android Screen 1)]

[image: MasterDetailPage by Default in Xamarin.Forms(Android Screen 2)]

But, earlier When I used to work in Xamarin.Forms, The Default MasterDetailPage was like as shown below:

[image: MasterDetailPage by Default in Xamarin.Forms]

So, I got confuse with the latest one and previous one default MasterDetailPage, both are completely different by the VIEW.

Comment: Yes , I am using MasterDetailPage only. you can check below screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably use the new Xamarin Forms Template of Visual Studio 2017, there is a bug that the `Master Detail` template is no MasterDetail at all, but uses a `TabbedPage`
[image: MasterDetail Template VS2017]

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53141 they probably didn't fix this, or at least not in a correct way ... https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90256/wrong-project-problematic-pages-template-issue-in-vs2017

Instead please see and use this sample https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/ in order to use a correct `MasterDetail`page template.

Xamarin Forms' Master Detail layout is just the same as as before.
[image: Master Detail]

Comment: Do you mean that we should not use the current MasterDetailPage Template (Which contains TabbedPage)?

Comment: So, If we want MasterDetailPage as earlier , We need to do manually in code , we can't use the present template. Is it correct?

Comment: That's correct, you have to create your MasterDetailPage on your own and should not use the default Visual Studio 2017 template, instead start with `Blank App`. You could use the sample that I linked as a basis. Or just use the "Master Detail Template" but keep in mind that it is not correct and you have to adjust everything, but the simplest way is to start from scratch with blank app

Comment: OK Johannes Thank you:-)

Comment: @Divya Vani It's a pleasure to help! Please keep in mind to accept the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ;)